# How to automatically login to other app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want a scenario like Facebook and Facebook Messenger in the way they login to facebook messenger directly when the user is logged-in to Facebook android app.

I have the same situation. I am having an android app and a different app (3rd party app) for chatting. 
Now, what I want is that if a user is already logged-in in our app it should automatically logged-in to other app.

This can be done by sending login details via intent, but as sending credentials of app over intent is not secure, so I cannot follow this thing.

Can anyone how can I achieve this, like Facebook also implement this.

Thanks a lot in advanced, it would be a great help if someone will help me here.

Comment: see content providers

Comment: Is there any other solution which can be fulfill my requirement ?